# Remove GenerateMember and Modifiers Properties in Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

I created a Button descendant where I hide all the properties I don't use.

I do it like this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[Bindable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
[Obsolete("", true)]
public new Boolean AllowDrop { get; set; }
```

Most properties get correctly hidden and cannot be used.

However there are two properties that I cannot get rid of.

[image]

Is there a way to also remove GenerateMember and Modifiers in the Designer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a new [`ControlDesigner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) for your control and override its [`PostFilterProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.postfilterproperties?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method. The method lets you to change or remove the items within the dictionary of properties.

The keys in the dictionary of properties are the names of the properties. Although [`Modifiers` and `GenerateMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) are not actual properties of your control and they are design-time properties, you can still remove them this way:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[Designer(typeof(MyCustomControlDesigner))]
public class MyCustomControl:Button
{
}
public class MyCustomControlDesigner:ControlDesigner
{
   protected override void PostFilterProperties(System.Collections.IDictionary properties)
   {
       base.PostFilterProperties(properties);
       properties.Remove("Modifiers");
       properties.Remove("GenerateMember");
   }
}
```

To hide properties in property grid, Instead of overriding or shadowing them, you can do the same thing for them.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat offtopic. Mostly for those, who are struggling with disabling the "Dock in Parent Container" attribute.
Following override helped me:

```
protected override void PostFilterAttributes(IDictionary attributes)
    {
        base.PostFilterAttributes(attributes);

        var oDockingAttribute = attributes.Values.OfType<DockingAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        var oNoDockingAttribute = new DockingAttribute(DockingBehavior.Never);

        if (oDockingAttribute != null) attributes[oDockingAttribute.TypeId] = oNoDockingAttribute;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove it because it is not a Class Property but a Design-Time Property and used only by the designer:

> If you have played with Whidbey builds of Visual Studio, you may have
>   noticed this new property called GenerateMember that shows up in the
>   property grid for all controls and components you add to a Windows
>   Form. Wondering what it is about? It is actually a design time
>   extender property that allows you to control whether a component added
>   to the form is referenced by a member variable in the class or a local
>   variable in InitializeComponent. By default, it is set to true, but if
>   you have any components that you are not really referencing outside of
>   InitializeComponent, you can set it to false. That way you can limit
>   the member variables in your class to only the components you really
>   need member variables for – just something to prevent clutter.

Same applies to `Modifiers` and `Locked`.

Comment: Although `Modifiers` and `GenerateMember` are not actual properties of a control and are design-time properties, but you can remove them by creating a custom `Designer` form control and overriding `PostFilterProperties` like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38771092/3110834).